# Send feedback from Win 8 app

Tags: windows-8, store, feedback

How can I send and receive the user feedback from an Windos Store App?
I can't use email because there is no free library for this.
While searching on this topic I found this [Feedback from user to developer without involving Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16814699/feedback-from-user-to-developer-without-involving-google-play) . Does it worth to port the ideea?

Comment: Your above idea seems good. You can also create web service, which gets feedback and store into database.

Comment: I would like to use an existing service to store the feedbacks

Comment: check out [Windows Azure Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/) probably an hour or two of work and everything pushed into a SQL database that you can slice and dice

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about store user feedback on free micro instance of Amazone Cloud?

Comment: Is free for one year as I can see. Anyway I'm looking for a simple solution.